# How to get value in C# from java script?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need to get a value that I got in Javascript to my code behind file..

My design code is:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatusOverview" runat="server" Width="95px" onchange="CheckSelectedItem(this)" >

</asp:DropDownList>
```

I'm using the dropwonlist in "ItemTemplate" of asp:ListView.

My javascript coding is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckSelectedItem(ddl) {
alert(ddl.value);
}
```

I want to get that "dll.value" value in code behind.. I already used Webmethod concept. But my problem is I need to get the value in ".ascx" page.. How to do that..?

I don't know how to use hidden field value concept too..

Comment: use server side methods, OnSelectedIndexChanged...and read values from arguments

Comment: I coudln't use the "OnSelectedIndexChanged" method as I'm using it inside a table..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this :

Add a hidden field element :

`<input  name='lala' id='lala' type='hidden'/>`

Add this :

```
function CheckSelectedItem(ddl) {
  document.getElementByID('lala').value=ddl.value;
}
```

On server side :

you can get the value by :

`Request.Form["lala"].ToString();`

---

Accoring to your comment :

> If I want to call a server side function from javascript with this
>   "ddl.value" means, how to do that?

Please read this

[ASP.NET pass a javascript value in server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649387/asp-net-pass-a-javascript-value-in-server-side)

Comment: Thanks..
If I want to call a server side function from javascript with this "ddl.value" means, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a hidden field.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckSelectedItem(ddl) {
        document.getElementByID('hfStatus').value = ddl.value;

        // if using jQuery
        // $("hfStatus").val(ddl.value);
    }
</script>

<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfStatus" />
```

Now you can directly access `hfStatus` from code-behind.